# Install loki using helm chart, and configure with existing grafana dashboard

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki, promtail

I have already deployed grafana dashboard in dev environment. then I want to deploy loki-promtail in stage and prod environment using helm chart. so how to configure with loki-promtail and grafana.

**Note**:- I can't do install grafana in stage and prod environment. i want only install loki-promtail in all environment and configure with grafana.